# Eclipse e4 migrating 3.x plugin to 4.x?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have been working with Eclipse RCP for over a week now, and I've now been given an Eclipse plugin written in 3.x, which I need to migrate to 4.x. I'm using a book called Eclipse 4 RCP by Lars Vogel which has a small section on this, but I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm to do.

I'm trying to do this throught the use of the compatiblity layer. It mentions to add a couple of features for this (org.eclipse.rcp, org.eclipse.emf.ecore, org.eclipse.emf.common) and your ready to go, but I don't exactly know what I'm to do here. Like do I add these to the existing product file of the 3.x plugin I've been given, or do I create a separate e4 project and point to that. Many of the tutorials I read are a bit vague with the details and its a shame there's no proper step by step guide for beginners with this. Any help would be great.

Comment: What is the 4.x RCP? Is it a pure e4 RCP or a 3.x compatibility mode RCP? Converting a 3.x plugin to pure e4 can be very difficult / impossible.

Comment: It's a 3.x compatibility mode RCP.

Comment: Then you shouldn't have to do anything extra if you already have the RCP build working.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should be creating a separate e4 plug-in project for this. And where you have to configure your extensions/extension points in e4 ways.

Basically, like creating a new project.

If you want to migrate your Eclipse 3.x RCP application to the Eclipse 4 programming model, you can't directly reuse existing plugin.xml based user interface components, e.g. Views or Editors based on the definition in plugin.xml .

Components based on the plugin.xml file must be adjusted to avoid inheritance of Eclipse classes and to use the programming model based on @Inject . They also must be contributed to the application model.

Components which are not directly based on the plugin.xml file must be adjusted if they use Eclipse 3.x singletons, as for example Platform or PlatformUI , to access Eclipse API

you may want to take a look at this page: https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2013/february/article3.php

Comment: Thank you, I looked at that page earlier and gone through some of what it says, but it would of been better if it went through a more detailed implementation of how exactly to do it. I'll try this again starting with a new eclipse 4 plug-in project and see how I get on.